# Getting error in docker-compose.yml; can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key

Tags: docker, yaml

I am not a yaml programmer. I understand I have made a formatting/indentation error. But don't understand how to fix it. This is the error "can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key"

Error is thrown after environment:

This is my code:

```
version: “3.7”
services:

  nethermind:
    hostname: nethermind
    container_name: nethermind
    image: nethermind/nethermind:latest
    restart: always
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.32.100
    ports:
      — “30303:30303/tcp”
      — “30303:30303/udp”
    volumes:
-/home/<user>/nethermind/nethermind_db:/nethermind/nethermind_db
      — /home/<user>/nethermind/keystore:/nethermind/keystore
      — /home/<user>/nethermind/logs:/nethermind/logs
      — /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      — /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      — NETHERMIND_CONFIG=xdai
    logging:
      driver: “local”
 
networks:
  net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        — subnet: “192.168.32.0/24”
```

I tried changing indentation. Tried changing =xdai for :xdai. But my knowledge isn't good enough. Tried cleaning it up in yaml checker / llint, but no success

Comment: Try to search and replace from “ to "

Comment: This worked! And made me realize that also the minus signs weren’t simple ascii characters but were Unicode em. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally when programming, be careful to avoid weird ASCII characters that ressemble the classic character. To the computer they are not the same.

Nevers paste into Microsoft word or excel as they tend to do such changes silently.

Be careful if you work with Japanese people, their space character is not necessaraly standard (and that's a hard one to catch if your IDE doesn't warn you)